# Find specific duplicate values in array

Tags: c#, arrays, drag-and-drop, mouseevent, picturebox

For the past few months I have been working on a school jigsaw puzzle programing project in school.

> Please bear the fact that this is a school project in mind when answering, because it is important for me to learn for myself, but I'm here because I'm really stuck and I would really appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

As it stands, the program loads four pictures from a specified folder and places them randomly on the screen.

[image: Program while active]

So far:

- The program expects the pictures to follow a naming convention, which is; `pic0` to `pic3`.
- The objective of the puzzle is to click and drag the four pieces of the puzzle until they match.
- I have figured out how to grip each piece with the mouse and drag them around.
- I have a array called `grabbedAll` which helps me ensure that only one piece is moved at once, otherwise as the cursor passes over each piece, it also moves.

This works great when they are separate, but when they overlap, two or more picture boxes are set to true, which means they both end up moving.

I have seen solutions with linq to check whenever a dublicate value appears in an array, but I need a way to check whenever a array has duplicate "true" in it.

Their solutions won't work for me because it's a bool array and therefore can only be `true` or `false`.

**My current code:**

```
void ImgBox_MouseDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    grabbed = true;

    //MessageBox.Show("Down");

    for (int i = 0; i < antBox; i++)
    {
        if (MouX >= PicBoxes[i, 0] && MouX <= PicBoxes[i, 0] + Imglinking[i].Width && MouY >= PicBoxes[i, 1] && MouY <= PicBoxes[i, 1] + Imglinking[i].Height)
        {
            grabbedAll[i] = true;

        }

    }

    label1.Text = "grabbed = " + grabbed;

}

void ImgBox_MouseUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    grabbed = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < antBox; i++)
    {
        grabbedAll[i] = false;

    }

    //MessageBox.Show("Up");

    label1.Text = "grabbed = " + grabbed;

}

void ImgBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{ //start

    MouX = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X;

    MouY = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y;

    label2.Text = "X: " + System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X + "\nY: " + System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y;

    if (grabbed == true)
    {
        //e.Button == MouseButtons.Left

        for (int i = 0; i < antBox; i++)
        {
            if (MouX >= PicBoxes[i, 0] && MouX <= PicBoxes[i, 0] + Imglinking[i].Width && MouY >= PicBoxes[i, 1] && MouY <= PicBoxes[i, 1] + Imglinking[i].Height)
            {
                if (grabbedAll[i] == true)
                {
                    PicBoxes[i, 0] = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X - (Imglinking[i].Width / 2);

                    PicBoxes[i, 1] = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y - (Imglinking[i].Height / 2);

                    ImgBox[i].Location = new Point(PicBoxes[i, 0], PicBoxes[i, 1]);

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Instead of posting the project abstract and whole code, can you please edit the question with necessary information only?

Comment: Am I right: grabbedAll[] should only contain one "true" entry?

Comment: Why do you want to check whether array contains duplicate `true` (and then write long program to resolve this situation) rather than prevent this situation to happen (which is much easier to do)?

Comment: @Florianp.i. Yes, I have made so if duplicate true happens it will just make them all false and prevent them from all moving, this is the easiest way I know.

Comment: @Ňuf I don't know how I would do that, I select picture boxes by checking it's relative coordinates at the moment (x, y, x+lenght, y+height) and if the screen coordinates of the mouse is inside that room that picture box can move.

Comment: @un-lucky marc_s edited my question, hope he made it more clear than I could have written it.

Comment: @Simon It's very simple. In `ImgBox_MouseDown` call `break;` just after `grabbedAll[i] = true;`. It immediately exits from `for` loop so only the first picture of those under mouse cursor will have `grabbedAll` set to true. This has one little flaw, that it won't necessarily select the top-most picture (which might be confusing for user of your application), it's up to you to fix this if you want.

Comment: @Ňuf Yes thanks! This is exacly what I wanted, I have only a week left to complete it so I will probably aim to solve other elements in the meantime. Biggest problem was that they got stuck in each other, but now they won't. Thanks again!